# Extract part between two substrings in NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have a `NSString` and I want to extract a part between two substrings from this string.

Example string: `https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/limbo/id656951157?l=en&mt=8`

How to get the app id `656951157`, which is between `id` and `?`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of searching for substrings ("id", "?") you could convert the string to an URL and get its last path component:

```
NSString *urlString = @"https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/limbo/id656951157?l=en&mt=8";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSString *lastComp = [url lastPathComponent]; // id656951157
if ([lastComp length] >= 3) {
    // Strip initial "id":
    NSString *appId = [lastComp substringFromIndex:2];
    NSLog(@"%@", appId);
    // 656951157
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use component separator `[yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@"id"];` which will give you an array with 2 values. Second value will be having `656951157?l=en&mt=8`. Again use `componentsSeparatedByString` with ? to split this string then you can get `656951157`.

Comment: What if the path contains more occurrences of "id"? Such as `https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/xyzid/id656951157?l=en&mt=8`.

Comment: I don't think this path will contain more occurrences. But in that case have to make sure which id we need.

Answer (score 0):

Try below using regularexpression:-

```
  NSString *urlString = @"https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/limbo/id656951157?l=en&mt=8";
 NSString *URLRegExPattern = @"(?=id).*(?=//?l=en&mt=8 )";

   NSError *regExErr;

   NSRegularExpression *URLRegEx = 
   [NSRegularExpression 
regularExpressionWithPattern:URLRegExPattern 
                                                                         options:0
                                                                        error:&regExErr];

  NSRange range = [URLRegEx 
  rangeOfFirstMatchInString:urlString
                                        options:0 
                                          range:NSMakeRange(0, urlString.length)];

  if (!NSEqualRanges(range, 
 NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0))) {
NSString *appId = [urlString substringWithRange:range];
}

  NSLog(@"appId: %@", appId);:-
```